# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when trying to use three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm having trouble importing three js into my project.
First I ran:

I'm following the documentation here: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation

I ran this in my VS code terminal for my folder project:

```
npm install --save three
```

Then I created the boilerplate HTML and linked it to my JS file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebGL</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then I just copy and pasted the documentation code into the JavaScript file:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
//etc.
```

, but I'm getting this error:

[image]

If I change my script to this:

```
<script src="app.js" type="module" ></script>
```

I get this error:

[image]

Here's my folder structure, everything seems to work link wise, because when I do "alert("Hello World)" my JS file works on the live server VS code.

[image]

Why is my import statement causing my error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are following [this documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation)…

Read the paragraph after the code example you are cribbing:

> When installing from npm, you'll almost always use some sort of bundling tool to combine all of the packages your project requires into a single JavaScript file. While any modern JavaScript bundler can be used with three.js, the most popular choice is webpack.

You aren't doing that. You're trying to load it directly into the browser.

Look at the following example.

You need to:

- Use the URL to the file and not depend on node.js's extensionless module resolution system
- Use a `type="module"` script

Generally speaking, a better approach is to write your code using a bundler like Webpack or Parcel.

Comment: thanks! I install parcel and now it works. I'll accept this answer when it lets me (3 mins left)